# Is there a Spring Expression Language editor?

Tags: spring

We using SpEL quite a lot in our web application, sometimes the expressions can be very long and complex, is there any javascript powered editor for SpEL?

something like a plugin for codemirror ?

Comment: How about this? https://github.com/benmarch/spel2js

Comment: IntelliJ Ultimate Edition has SpEL support as well